# What does the compiler mean?

Tags: haskell

I have following applicative expression and I know it is wrong:

```
Prelude> [Just (*2), Just (+9)] <*> [(Just 3),(Just 4), (Just 5)]
```

and the compiler complains:

```
<interactive>:2:2: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Maybe Integer -> b'
                  with actual type `Maybe (Integer -> Integer)'
    * Possible cause: `Just' is applied to too many arguments
      In the expression: Just (* 2)
      In the first argument of `(<*>)', namely `[Just (* 2), Just (+ 9)]'
      In the expression:
        [Just (* 2), Just (+ 9)] <*> [(Just 3), (Just 4), (Just 5)]
    * Relevant bindings include it :: [b] (bound at <interactive>:2:1)
```

What does the compiler is trying to say?

This error message:

```
* Couldn't match expected type `Maybe Integer -> b'
              with actual type `Maybe (Integer -> Integer)'
```

it means this part `[Just (*2), Just (+9)]` of the expression?

Let's look the signature of the function `(<*>)`:

```
(<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

substitute it with `List` and `Maybe` type constructor above:

```
(<*>) :: [] (Maybe Integer -> b) -> [] (Maybe Integer) -> [] b
```

Which type should the `b` have?

Comment: It expects something of type `Maybe Integer -> b` for some `b` but you've given it `Maybe (Integer -> Integer)`. But that is just restating what the compiler has stated. What part of this error have you misunderstood? (The error is indeed referring to `[Just (*2), Just (+9)]`, but that is also clearly stated in the error itself. The type variable `b` refers to any type - hence why it is a free type variable)

Comment: Awesome, now I see. `Maybe (Integer -> Integer)` is not a function, but rather just only a type. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's substitute more carefully

```
(<*>) :: (Applicative f) => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
[Just (*2), Just (+9)] :: [Maybe (Int -> Int)]   --wlog
[Just 3, Just 4, Just 5] :: [Maybe Int]
```

So `f = []`, thus:

```
(<*>) :: [a -> b] -> [a] -> [b]
```

But now we are to match `[a -> b]` against `[Maybe (Int -> Int)]` and that's impossible -- a function and a `Maybe` can't be the same.  You are trying to do function application under *two* functors, not just one.  I.e. you would need something of type

```
f (g (a -> b)) -> f (g a) -> f (g b)
```

Fortunately, that's easy to make:  `liftA2 (<*>)`.

Or, if you want something fancier, you could operate instead on the composite functor [`Compose [] Maybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html).

```
getCompose $ Compose [Just (*2), Just (+9)] <*> Compose [Just 3, Just 4, Just 5]
```

(But when `Compose` is cool is when you don't immediately `getCompose` the result, but use it as an important abstraction in whatever program you are writing.)

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is referring to this part of your code (`In the expression: Just (* 2)`):

```
[Just (*2), Just (+9)] <*> [(Just 3),(Just 4), (Just 5)]
 ^^^^^^^^^
```

It's also saying that the actual type of `Just (*2)` is `Maybe (Integer -> Integer)`, but the way you're using it requires a value of type `Maybe Integer -> b` (for some type `b`).

If you look at the type of

```
(<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

you can see that the first argument must be some type constructor `f` applied to a function type `a -> b`. You have a list of values, so `f` is `[]`.

Therefore the first argument must be a list of functions, but what you have is a list of `Maybe`s. That's why this code is an error.

The rest of the error message comes from the second argument of `<*>`, `[(Just 3),(Just 4), (Just 5)]`, which is a list of arguments (for the list of functions in the first argument). That is, the compiler knows it needs a value of type `f a` and you gave it `[(Just 3),(Just 4), (Just 5)]`, so it deduces `f = []`, `a = Maybe Integer`.

So the type of the first argument `f (a -> b)` becomes `[] (Maybe Integer -> b)` (which is the same as `[Maybe Integer -> b]`). `b` here is completely free. You can use whatever result type you want and you'll get `f b` (i.e. `[b]` (a list of results)) back from `<*>`.

Answer (score 2):

There's a wrong substitution here:

```
(<*>) :: [] (Maybe Integer -> b) -> [] (Maybe Integer) -> [] b
```

`[Just (*2), Just (+9)]` has the following type: `Num a => [Maybe (a -> a)]`

That's because `List` is `f` in `(<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`.

According to the `(<*>)`'s type, you can have:

```
[(*2), (+9)] <*> [2, 3]
```

Or

```
Just (*2) <*> Just 2
```

and `[]` and `Maybe` will be Applicative contexts in these expressions correspondingly, but not both, using just `(<*>)`

The following esoteric expression will compile:

```
[(Just (*2) <*>), (Just (+9) <*>)] <*> [(Just 3), (Just 4), (Just 5)]
```

But I'm not sure it is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
Prelude> [Just (*2), Just (+9)] <*> [(Just 3),(Just 4), (Just 5)]
```

instruction there are two functors. The outer one is `List` and the inner one is `Maybe` So when you put the `<*>` applicative operation in between two lists the first list should contain some function type elements to become an applicative functor, such as;

```
Prelude> [(+1),(*2)] <*> [1,2]
[2,3,2,4]
```

However in your instruction the first list just contains some `Maybe` values. This doesn't qualify the list as an applicative functor. But the elements of the list are of type `Maybe (a -> b)`. That means not the list  itself but it's contents are applicative functors. So in order to turn our list into an applicative list, you are expected replace the applicative Maybe values with a function which takes an applicative `Maybe (a -> b)` and a `Maybe a` and gives a `Maybe b` In another words `f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` and this happens to be `<*>` operator.

So if you rephrase your code as follows you will get the expected result;

```
Prelude> (<*>) <$> [Just (*2), Just (+9)] <*> [(Just 3),(Just 4),(Just 5)]
[Just 6,Just 8,Just 10,Just 12,Just 13,Just 14]
```